# Can we connect TN3270 emulator by Mochasoft using VBA?

Tags: mainframe

We are currently using TN3270 emualtor by Mochasoft.. We have earlier used Rocket Bluezone and it is interacting with VBA using HLLAPI.

Mocha has inbuilt macro support.. But Is it possible for Mochasoft as well using VBA Macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the documentation to suggest that you can.  Have you contacted the developer to ask?  Also, you could look at using AutoHotKey, which may be able to bridge between VBA and other things.